# The most efficient way to simplify Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that looks for the names of the classes to then include the libraries according to the editor to find. It checks the function declaration to know if the library has already been imported.

The code works fine but it repeats.

**The question** : Is there less simplification of the following code

**The problem** : I cannot pass variable to the anonymous function of `$.getScript`

```
function wfRunEditors(reScann) {
    if ($('.wfe-editorjs').length) {
        if ('undefined' === typeof initWfEditorJS) {
            $.getScript('/src/libs/js/editorjs.full.min.js', function () {
                $.getScript('/src/js/editor/wfeditorjs.js', function () {
                    $.loadCSS('/src/css/editors/editorjs.min.css');
                    wfCheckerFunction['editorjs'] = true;
                    initWfeditorjs(reScann);
                });
            });
        } else {
            wfCheckerFunction['editorjs'] = true;
            initWfeditorjs(reScann);
        }
    }
    if ($('.wfe-trumbowyg').length) {
        if ('undefined' === typeof initWfTrumbowyg) {
            $.getScript('/src/libs/js/trumbowyg.full.min.js', function () {
                $.getScript('/src/js/editor/wftrumbowyg.js', function () {
                    $.loadCSS('/src/css/editors/trumbowyg.min.css');
                    wfCheckerFunction['trumbowyg'] = true;
                    initWftrumbowyg(reScann);
                });
            });
        } else {
            wfCheckerFunction['trumbowyg'] = true;
            initWftrumbowyg(reScann);
        }
    }
    // add other editors
}
```

**Solution** :

- I have minified all the js files
- the init functions and the one that includes the css are called at the end of the minified file
- I globalised the variable reScann

```
function wfRunEditors() {
    let editors = [
        'editorjs',
        'trumbowyg'
        // add other editors
    ];
    for (i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
        if ($('.wfe-' + editors[i]).length) {
            if ('undefined' === typeof window['initWf' + editors[i]]) {
                $.getScript('/src/js/editor/' + editors[i] + '.full.min.js');
            } else {
                wfCheckerFunction[editors[i]] = true;
                window['initWf' + editors[i]]();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _...the code works fine but it repeats..._ Put the redundant part into a single function

Comment: You could create a function wfRunEditor (pay attention to the singular form) and start by just getting one editor down and create the function signature for this one. Try using this function on the other editor and generalize the arguments and the body of the function to work with more than one editor.

Comment: @mikemols I cannot pass variable to the anonymous function of $.getScript

Comment: @Ðidou there's no reason to. it can close around variables in scopes above it. Your code as written already does this.

Comment: Unless you actually know for a fact that you are going to add more then 3 or 4, this is really just academic.  As a developer, we should be applying our time and thoughts into the requests that provide the most bang of the buck.  This would definitely fall into the [Premature Optimization](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/).

Comment: @erik-philips it has happened to me before but I hope not this time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**First:** Both `if` statements haven't exactly the same structure:

- in the first you load a script named like the editor but with a `wf` before:
  `'/src/js/editor/wfeditorjs.js'` but in the second you do it without: `'/src/js/editor/trumbowyg.js'`
- in the second `if` statement you are additionally loading a css file: `$.loadCSS('/src/libs/css/trumbowyg.min.css');`

---

If both `if` statement have exactly the same structure and the called function doesn't use the editor name in camelCase (f.e. `initWfeditorjs` instead of `initWfEditorJS`) you could just save an array with the editor names and loop over them in a `for`-loop.

In that loop you could "build" your selector- and src-strings by concatenation with the editor name, for example `$('.wfe-' + editors[i])`, and call the function with: `window['yourFunctionName'](your_function_param)`, for example `window['initWf' + editors[i]](reScann)`.

Furthermore: You don't need to pass a variable to the anonymous function if that variable is declared globally like your `reScann` variable.

**Example:**

```js
function wfRunEditors(reScann) {
    let editors = [
        'editorjs',
        'trumbowyg'
    ];
    
    for (i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
        if ($('.wfe-' + editors[i]).length) {
            if ('undefined' === typeof window['initWf' + editors[i]]) {
                $.getScript('/src/libs/js/' + editors[i] + '.full.min.js', function () {
                    $.getScript('/src/js/editor/wf' + editors[i] + '.js', function () {
                        $.loadCSS('/src/libs/css/' + editors[i] + '.min.css');
                        wfCheckerFunction[editors[i]] = true;
                        window['initWf' + editors[i]](reScann);
                    });
                });
            } else {
                window['initWf' + editors[i]](reScann);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for, but the problem I can't pass variable to the anonymous function of the $.getScript method, so editors[i] return undefined

Comment: I changed the name of the files and the function and I added the other loadCSS

Comment: I will watch it later. Now i am in the train on the way at home...

Comment: You don't need to pass a variable to the anonymous function if that variable is declared globally like your ```reScann``` variable. I allthough tested it with ```editors[i]``` and got the editor names. But that was after i fixed a mistake of mine (i forgot the quotation marks arround the editor names ;)>

Comment: thank you I modified your script a little, look at the solution

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you. But you aren't calling the function in the second ```if``` anymore after loading the script. Is that on purpose or a mistake?

Comment: It's true I forgot to call the wfCheckerFunction () function, for the other functions I call them inside the file ... full.min.je, again thank you.

Comment: if you need anything tell me, otherwise I have developed some tools if you are interested [link](https://packagist.org/packages/arvodia/)